# Example of a bounded integrable function $f: [0,3]\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need a example of a bounded integrable function $f: [0,3]\to \mathbb{R}$ for which the associated
function $F : [0,3]\to\mathbb{R}$ , defined by $F(x) := \int_{0}^{x}f$ for all $x\in [0,3]$, is differentiable when $x\in [0,2)\cup(2,3]$ but not differentiable when x = 2.

Im not sure whether a simple piecewise function such as the following would work.:
$$ \begin{equation} 
  f(x) = \begin{cases}& 2, \ 0 \leq x < 2 \\
 & 3, \ 2 < x \leq 3 \\ 
\end{cases}
   \end{equation}
$$

Any examples would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Your example works !

Comment: Your example works. Since it has finite discontinuities it is (Riemann) integrable, and it is differentiable on $[0,2) \cup (2,3] $ (with the derivative being 0 at all points in $[0,2) \cup (2,3] $). Since the function is not defined at $x = 2$ it is not differentiable there.

Comment: $f(2)=0,\ f(x)=\sin(\frac 1{x-2})$ for an $f$ with an essential discontinuity.